Is it possible to consolidate the JSON data in every lambda_handler execution during AWS S3 Batch operation?
This is my lambda handler sample
import logging
import json
from urllib import parse
import boto3
import os
import traceback
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel("INFO")

aws_region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']

s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
session = boto3.Session()
# session = boto3.Session(region_name=aws_region)
s3_client = session.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("S3 Migration Lambda Handler with [AWS_REGION]: %s", aws_region)
    invocation_id = event["invocationId"]
    invocation_schema_version = event["invocationSchemaVersion"]
    results = []
    result_code = None
    result_string = None
    json_data_list = []
    json_filename='dummy-file-name.json'
    output_bucket='s3migration-meta-info'
    invocation_id = event["invocationId"]
    
    for task in event['tasks']:
        task_id = task["taskId"]  
        logger.info("[INVOCATION_ID]: %s, [INVOCATION_SCHEMA_VERSION]: %s, [TASK]: %s, [TASK_ID]: %s", invocation_id, invocation_schema_version, task, task_id)

        s3_migration_source_bucket = task['s3Bucket']
        s3_migration_source_object_key = task['s3Key']
        s3_migration_source_object_version_id = task['s3VersionId']
        destination_bucket_name = s3_migration_source_bucket + '-migrated'
        logger.info("[SOURCE_BUCKET]: %s, [OBJECT_KEY]: %s, [VERSION_ID]: %s, [TARGET_BUCKET]: %s", s3_migration_source_bucket, s3_migration_source_object_key, s3_migration_source_object_version_id, destination_bucket_name)
        
        try:
            response = s3_client.copy_object(
                    Bucket=destination_bucket_name,
                    Key=s3_migration_source_object_key,
                    CopySource={'Bucket': s3_migration_source_bucket, 'Key': s3_migration_source_object_key, 'VersionId': s3_migration_source_object_version_id},
                    Metadata={"x-version": s3_migration_source_object_version_id},
                    MetadataDirective='REPLACE'
                )
            logger.info("Copied successfully [RESPONSE]: %s", response)
            new_version_id = response['VersionId']
            result_string = f"Copied successfully ObjectKey: {s3_migration_source_object_key} and versionId: {s3_migration_source_object_version_id} to bucket: {destination_bucket_name}"
            result_code = "Succeeded"
            error = None
        except ClientError as error:
            error = str(e)
            logger.error("An error occurred during S3 object copy operation:")
            logger.error(error)
            if error.response["Error"]["Code"] == "NoSuchKey":
                result_code = "Succeeded"
            else:
                result_code = "PermanentFailure"
                result_string = "Got exception when applying revision type "
                logger.exception(result_string)

        json_data = {
                'invocation_id' : invocation_id,
                'from_bucket'   : s3_migration_source_bucket,
                'to_bucket'     : destination_bucket_name,
                'object_key'    : s3_migration_source_object_key,
                'version_id'    : s3_migration_source_object_version_id,
                'new_version_id': new_version_id,
                'status'        : result_code,
                'error'         : error
            }
        logger.info("JSON Data: ", json_data)
        
    json_content = json.dumps(json_data_list)
    
    # Write JSON data to a local file
    local_file_path = '/tmp/json_data.json'
    with open(local_file_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(json_content, f)
        
    response_put_object = s3_resource.Object(output_bucket, json_filename).put(Body=open(local_file_path, 'rb'))
    print(f"File uploaded successfully to s3://{output_bucket}/{json_filename}")
    logger.info("JSON Data saved %s", response_put_object)

I am trying to invoke this AWS Lambda function via AWS S3 Batch Operations,
and intention is to copy every object with its all versions from Bucket-A to Bucket-B.
I am trying to construct a JSON data with its status whether the specific item copied successfully or not as follow:
[
  {
    "object_key": "123",
    "version_id": "123",
    "status": "copied"
  },
  {
    "object_key": "123",
    "version_id": "123",
    "status": "copied"
  }
]

To track activities of copy operation.
My understanding is whenever lambda_handler is been invoked it is running as a slave node and because of this nature I cannot consolidate all items at once, which eventually happening is the report file is getting upload for number of times with number of versions creates at AWS S3 side.
As per screen shot

My intention is to consolidate all objects with its versionId data in JSON and then upload this file one time only, this way I can manage the report data efficiently.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-examples-reports.html - you should use the reporting from the batch job directly. Optionally you can then have a lambda listening for the completion report file and transform and reupload that one.
